# $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 0$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda = \{n+m\omega \mid n,m \in \mathbb{Z}, \omega^3=1, \omega \not= 1\}$

Tags: elliptic-curves, complex-geometry

I am rather stuck trying to prove that $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda = \{n+m\omega \mid n,m \in \mathbb{Z}, \omega^3=1, \omega \not= 1\}$. Could you help?

Comment: Do you know that every elliptic curve is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ for some lattice $\Lambda$? (the so-called uniformization theorem for elliptic curves.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo I know that every elliptic curve is the image of some the function $F: \mathbb{C}/\Lambda \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2 $ sending $z \mapsto (\wp(z):\wp'(z):1)$ where $\wp$ is the Weierstrass $\wp$-function for the lattice $\Lambda$. Is this what you mean?